# How to build TensorFlow Lite as a static library and link to it from a separate (CMake) project?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I've successfully built a simple C++ app running [TF Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/) model by adding my sources to `tensorflow/lite/examples`, similarly to what [the official C++ TF guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) suggests for full TF. Now I want to build it as a separate project (shared library) linking to TF Lite statically and using CMake as a build system.

I tried to add a custom target to my `CMakeLists.txt`, which would build TF Lite with Bazel:

```
set(TENSORFLOW_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/tensorflow)
add_custom_target(TFLite
    COMMAND bazel build //tensorflow/lite:framework
    COMMAND bazel build //tensorflow/lite/kernels:builtin_ops
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TENSORFLOW_DIR})
```

I chose those Bazel targets because the `BUILD` file from `tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal` has them as dependencies, and they work for me when I build
my code with Bazel within TF repo. Not sure if that's enough.

Then I manually collect include dirs (with that ugly temporarily hardcoded path) and libs:

```
set(TFLite_INCLUDES
    ${TENSORFLOW_DIR}
    ~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_azymohliad/ec8567b83922796adb8477fcbb00a36a/external/flatbuffers/include)

set(TFLite_LIBS
    ${TENSORFLOW_DIR}/bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/libframework.pic.a)
    
target_include_directories(MyLib ... PRIVATE ... ${TFLite_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(MyLib ... ${TFLite_LIBS})
```

And with this configuration, I get many undefined references to TFLite stuff during linkage. I checked with `nm` and those symbols are indeed missing in `libframework.pic.a`, I found some of them in various `.o` files in Bazel output. Manually picking all those `.o` files seems wrong.

So, is it possible to link nicely to TF Lite from CMake like I'm trying to? Maybe is there some magical `bazel query include_dirs(//tensorflow/lite:framework)` command which would give me paths to all the necessary include dirs, and a similar command for libraries to link against so that I could pass this info to CMake?

Comment: Just a comment, I think you should be able to collect the flatbuffers headers from `bazel-genfiles/external` in the TensorFlow tree (after build) instead of `~/.cache/...`.

Comment: @jdehesa, thanks, that would be really useful, but for some reason, `bazel-genfiles` contains only `tensorflow` directory in my case and no `external`

Comment: Ah wait maybe it's another one, have you checked `bazel-bin/external` and `bazel-tensorflow/external`?

Comment: Anyway about your problem, the thing is each `.a` only contains the `.c` code of its goal, not the dependencies. Also, I haven't found any good way of tracking headers either. My way around this has been adding a code file and a new goal to the TF tree (in a new subdir) with dependency to what I needed. With a `cc_library` I'm not sure if you can get a `.a` containing everything through options, with a `cc_binary` you get at least a `.params` file under `bazel-bin` with all the `.a` dependencies that you can scan, or you can your make a `.so` (personally I'm on Windows and make a DLL nowadays)

Comment: About the headers, I used to painfully list all the necessary paths that I needed to copy, pretty much by trial and error. What I do now is I have my own wrapper for the library (a very simple interface where I can load a `.pb` model file and run it for given inputs), hiding every native TF type (pimpl mostly). It took a number of tricks but now I only need a couple of headers of mine and this DLL.

Comment: This is all for regular TF btw, not TF Lite. Now there is [TensorFlow for C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c), so that work has become kind of redundant, but I don't think there is an equivalent for Lite, so I thought the same approaches should work.

Comment: @jdehesa, thanks a lot for all your suggestions. Indeed, I found external headers in `bazel-tensorflow/external`. For the linkage, I really don't want to add any code to TF tree but to treat TF as a usual dependency, so I ended up adding all needed object files to `TFLite_LIBS` variable above and it works now. I made a script which goes through every undefined reference and look for object file defining it in `bazel-bin`, and after few iterations I collected everything I need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up listing all necessary TFLite object files manually for CMake's `target_link_libraries` (in the `TFLite_LIBS`) and it works.

I used a simple shell script to get the list of necessary object files.
First I collected all undefined references from build log into a bash-array as following:

```
SYMBOLS=(\
    'tflite::CombineHashes('\
    'tflite::IsFlexOp('\
    'tflite::ConvertArrayToTfLiteIntArray('\
    'tflite::EqualArrayAndTfLiteIntArray('\
    ...
    'tflite::ConvertVectorToTfLiteIntArray(')
```

Then for every symbol in that array, I went through every `*.o` file in bazel build output:

```
for SYMBOL in $SYMBOLS[@]; do
    for OBJ in $(find -L /path/to/tensorflow/bazel-bin/ -name '*.o'); do
        nm -C $OBJ | grep "T $SYMBOL" > /dev/null && echo $OBJ
    done
done | sort | uniq
```

and added the output to `TFLite_LIBS` in CMake (with correct path prefix, of course). After that, I got a new portion of undefined references, but after a few iterations, it resolved everything.

Probably I could also obtain the full list of dependencies from `*-params` file from my initial in-tree build, but a quick check showed that it had some redundant items, and the script collected only the necessary ones.

For include locations, I replaced that hardcoded path to flatbuffers in bazel cache with `${TENSORFLOW_DIR}/bazel-tensorflow/external/flatbuffers/include/`. Thanks [jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782792/jdehesa) for the hint.

**UPDATE**:
The native build of all-inclusive TF Lite static library can be done very similar to official build instructions for [RPi](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_rpi), [iOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_ios) or [ARM64](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64) using plain old make:
 1. `./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/download_dependencies.sh`
 2. `make -f tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile`

The output library will be stored as `<tensorflow-root>/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/<platform>/lib/libtensorflow-lite.a`. And the external dependencies with their headers would go into `<tensorflow-root>/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads` (for example `flatbuffers` headers are in `<tensorflow-root>/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include`).

Guide doesn't mention that make could be called directly. There are wrapper-scripts for different cross-compilation targets, which just set appropriate variables and run make. But by default make would just do native build. This make invokation can be added as a custom command in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: When I try to use the static library that is built with the updated approach I get an undefined reference error: ./tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/linux_x86_64/lib/libtensorflow-lite.a(nnapi_implementation.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::ASharedMemory_create(char const*, unsigned long)':
nnapi_implementation.cc:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `shm_open'   Do you maybe know where this comes from?

Comment: Okay I found that there is a build script called build_lib.sh which seems to turn off nnapi. Whith this I do not get this error anymore. However I am wondering what the nnapi is useful for and if it is only supported on some platforms?

Comment: @Marcel_marcel1991, I don't really know, sorry. And I still use the first approach: build with bazel, then manually list all files for linkage. I found it easier to maintain for multiple platforms.

Comment: Related to Make build: the `tensorflow/lite/tools/make/` contains only README file, stating `Using Makefile to build TensorFlow Lite is deprecated at the Aug 2021. Please use CMake or Bazel instead.`

Comment: Last tag which contains the Make files seems to be v2.6.3: https://github.com/devialet/tensorflow/tree/v2.6.3/tensorflow/lite/tools/make